# Why is the header section so far up than it should be when I justify-content?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Why is the header section so far up than it should be when I justify-content?

When I set justify content of the header__container to space around, the header starts to go way up beyond its margin. Please help.

```css
header {
  height: calc(100vh - 80px);
}

.header__container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 720px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header__container">
    <div class="header__description">
      <h1>Lebanon's most awarded online library platform</h1>
      <h2>Find your dream book with <span class="purple">Library</span></h2>
    </div>
    <figure class="header__img--wrapper">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="">
    </figure>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: tell me about result which you are waiting

Answer (score 1):

You've set the container height to 100%, but sometimes that's not enough height for your content. Because you've centered it some of the top is cut off, and same at the bottom.

Instead, set `min-height`.

```css
header {
  height: calc(100vh - 80px);
}

.header__container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 720px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header__container">
    <div class="header__description">
      <h1>Lebanon's most awarded online library platform</h1>
      <h2>Find your dream book with <span class="purple">Library</span></h2>
    </div>
    <figure class="header__img--wrapper">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="">
    </figure>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: it didn't work however it worked when i just changed the header height to 200vh instead of 100vh. Does that give us any explanation? @isherwood

Comment: @oissa  Why do you feel compelled to have a height on the header - since 200vh will force a scroll which feels odd for a header.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I just want it to take up a page that's all and i know 200vh isn't the efficient way but I want to know why 200vh is the height that is giving me the answer I want.

Answer (score 0):

Now i can see, when you use `flex-direction: column;` then your justify-content do  vertical aligment.

You don't need to use `flex-direction: column` in this case, because it's usual behavior for `display: block` elements

Comment: Yes I know. Thats what Im trying to do. I want the h1 and h2 and the img to take the whole section space.

Comment: okay, give me a second

Comment: Okay, i still can't understand, for now your header takes all page size

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `justify-content: space-around;` which on a small screen does what you say given you forced a height on the `header` (why?) yet have "bigger" items within it (your image).  Keep in mind that "too much CSS" is often the bane of it - less is more most often.

Note I put a border on so we can visually see the blocks.

```css
header {
  height: calc(100vh - 80px);
}

.header__container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 720px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /*justify-content: space-around;*/
}

.header__container>* {
  border: solid lime 1px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header__container">
    <div class="header__description">
      <h1>Lebanon's most awarded online library platform</h1>
      <h2>Find your dream book with <span class="purple">Library</span></h2>
    </div>
    <figure class="header__img--wrapper">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="">
    </figure>
  </div>
</header>
```

Alternate option: stop doing the height and let the "flow" flow.

```css
header {
  /*height: calc(100vh - 80px);*/
}

.header__container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 720px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.header__container>* {
  border: solid lime 1px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header__container">
    <div class="header__description">
      <h1>Lebanon's most awarded online library platform</h1>
      <h2>Find your dream book with <span class="purple">Library</span></h2>
    </div>
    <figure class="header__img--wrapper">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="">
    </figure>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: @oissa I added an answer regarding the sizing and the image - on a large screen yours is  OK but not on smaller with fixed image size.  Optional would be to force the image to reduce size - right now your question is about the "why is it up too far" vs what your desired output is; which is a different question and answer perhaps